# Classpath for Cordova android plugins

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

For my editor (vim with syntastic) I have to set the correct Java classpath of the android plugins, but I don't know what folder to add. On some other posting there is a bin folder mentioned that should contain the .class resp. .jar files. Unfortunately that folder doesn't exist anymore under Cordova 5.1.1.